# Laravel belongsTo query

Tags: php, laravel

Sorry, I event can't describe my issue in a simple question! So I'm just gonna write it down for better explanation.

I have 2 tables ..

### Order table:

```
id - status  
100 - success  
200 - pending
```

### Sales table :

```
id - order_id - user_id - amount 
1  - 100 - 5 - $20
2  - 200 - 5 - $30
```

### Sales model

```
class Sales extends Eloquent
{
    public function parentorder()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Order', 'order_id');
    }
}
```

I need to get the total amount for only the SUCESS orders

```
// get profits 
// this gives me = $50 
$profits = Sales::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->sum('amount')

// trying to do something like .. 
$profits = Sales::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('parentorder.status','Success')->sum('amount');
// so I get the correct total which is $20 (for the success order id=100)
```

ummm, any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**

```
$total = Sale::whereHas('orders', function($q)
{
    $q->where('status', '=', 'success');

})->sum('amount');
```

**Usage**

Call the variable `$total`.

Comment: Hi Rafael, Thank you, but this didn't work,  I need to get the total for only the order who has 'Success' status, not all of the orders .. where('status','Sucess') , so, where can I put this condition ?

Comment: Yes! that works! thanks a lot Rafael, really really appreciate your time.. Just one thing, if you could add a value the the sum(), because without a value it gets me an error .. just change sum() to sum('amount'), you properly forgot to add that .. Thanks again man! :)